# How to change a radio button's foreground color when clicked?

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button, controltemplate

I use my `ResourceDictionary` to style my `RadioButton`:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MenuButtonTheme"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Foreground="#7D8083"
                                    FontSize="14.59"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
                                    Margin="12,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </Style.Setters>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#22202f"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I click my `RadioButton`, the background color changes, while my foreground color doesn't.

This is how I apply the style:

```xml
<RadioButton Content="Dashboard"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"/>
```

I followed [this tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzP8mw7JUzI) (the `RadioButton` theming starts here @10:00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is [dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list). The value assigned to the `Foreground` property in the `TextBlock` within the control template takes precedence over the trigger in the style. You can move setting the `Foreground` to a setter in the style and use `TemplateBinding`:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
       x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
   <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7D8083"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
               <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                             Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             FontSize="14.59"
                             FontWeight="Bold"
                             FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
                             Margin="12,0,0,0" />
               </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Transparent" />
   </Style.Setters>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
               Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background"
                 Value="#22202f" />
         <Setter Property="Foreground"
                 Value="Red" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

An alternative is to use `ControlTemplate.Triggers` and target the `TextBlock` specifically.

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
       x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
   <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
               <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <TextBlock x:Name="RadioButton"
                             Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Foreground="#7D8083"
                             FontSize="14.59"
                             FontWeight="Bold"
                             FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
                             Margin="12,0,0,0" />
               </Grid>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                           Value="True">
                     <Setter TargetName="RadioButton"
                             Property="Foreground"
                             Value="Red" />
                  </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Transparent" />
   </Style.Setters>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
               Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background"
                 Value="#22202f" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know about the dependency property value precedence, since this is my first time making a ui in wpf (I come in a winform background)

Answer (score 0):

check the spelling of your foreground try to uppercase in red

```
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Style.Trigger`, objects in the `ControlTemplate` is not accessible.
Therefore, it must be processed within `ControlTemplate.Triggers`.

```xml
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" 
       x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7D8083" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="text"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                FontSize="14.59"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
                                Margin="12,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#22202f" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]